# SQL: Query multiple tables with one query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to query the following in SQL Server:

```
 Select...FROM Database.dbo.[Table 1], [Table 2], [Table 3]
```

and so on.

Instead of writing a unique select query for each table, I would like to write one, as follows:

```
 FROM Database.dbo.[All Tables]
```

What is the most effective way to do this?  I imagine I would need to define All Tables somehow and point them to the static list of tables I would like to query.

Thank you

Comment: Trying to select details of all tables?

Comment: How do you plan to use that data?

Comment: How does the tables relate to each other? What would be the result of such a query? It sounds like you want to create a view.

Comment: All the tables are in the same database.  I am just trying to write the same exact query against all the tables at once.

Comment: A union query might do the trick.

Comment: Does these tables have exactly the same stucture ?

Comment: You haven't replied to either answer below... and it looks like you re-posted the question with clarifications ***[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895342/build-a-view-to-query-multiple-tables-with-identical-column-names)***.  Note for the future that it's more the custom, here, to append an "EDIT" or an "UPDATE" to the end of your question, when you see how it could be clarified... rather than abandoning a question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of examples, of the kind of thing you might want to do.

1)  SIMPLEST:  to list all tables, this command will generate a listing of SQL commands that you can paste into a query window and execute:

```
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM ' + TABLE_NAME + ';  '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

2)  Adding the TABLE_NAME to each listing, and showing just the top 3 rows of each.  Also, though I usually just copy/paste them, you could try capturing all in a variable, then executing the variable contents with `EXECUTE`:

```
DECLARE @SQL_CMDS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL_CMDS = ''
SELECT @SQL_CMDS = @SQL_CMDS + CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), 
    'SELECT TOP 3 [' + TABLE_NAME +  '] = ''' + TABLE_NAME 
        + ''' ,* FROM ' + TABLE_NAME + ';  ')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES; 

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL_CMDS
```

3)  Putting in a `WHERE` clause, for all columns that might contain an order number column (if you're not sure whether it's `ORDERNO` or `OrderNumber` or `Order_Num`):

```
DECLARE @SQL_CMDS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL_CMDS = ''
SELECT @SQL_CMDS = @SQL_CMDS + CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), 
    'SELECT [' + TABLE_NAME +  '] = ''' + TABLE_NAME + ''' ,* FROM [' + TABLE_NAME 
    + ']  WHERE [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] = ''thisValueIWant'';')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE UPPER(COLUMN_NAME) LIKE '%ORDER%N%'
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME;

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL_CMDS
```

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
Select...FROM Database.dbo.[Table 1], [Table 2], [Table 3]
```

you MUST have at least columns of the same type in each table... then you could do this:

```
SELECT id(or whatever column you have in common) FROM table1
union
SELECT id(or whatever column you have in common) FROM table2
union
SELECT id(or whatever column you have in common) FROM table3
```

etc.