# Build a view to query multiple tables with identical column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to build a view so I can write a single query against it:

```
 FROM Datebase.dbo.[AllQtrs]
```

Using SQL Server's 'Create view' function, it spits out the following:

```
SELECT        
   dbo.[2010 Q3].*, dbo.[2010 Q4].*, 
   dbo.[2011 Q1].*, dbo.[2011 Q2].*, 
   dbo.[2011 Q3].*, dbo.[2011 Q4].*, 
   dbo.[2012 Q1].*, dbo.[2012 Q2].*, 
   dbo.[2012 Q3].*, dbo.[2013 Q2].*, 
   dbo.[2013 Q1].*, dbo.[2012 Q4].*, 
   dbo.[2014 Q1].*, dbo.[2013 Q4].*, 
   dbo.[2013 Q3].*, dbo.[2014 Q2].*
FROM            
   dbo.[2010 Q3] 
CROSS JOIN
   dbo.[2010 Q4] 
CROSS JOIN
   dbo.[2011 Q1] 
CROSS JOIN
   dbo.[2011 Q2] 
CROSS JOIN
   dbo.[2011 Q3] 
CROSS JOIN
   dbo.[2011 Q4] 
CROSS JOIN
   dbo.[2012 Q1] 
CROSS JOIN
   dbo.[2012 Q2] 
CROSS JOIN
   dbo.[2012 Q3] 
CROSS JOIN
   dbo.[2012 Q4] 
CROSS JOIN
   dbo.[2013 Q1] 
CROSS JOIN
   dbo.[2013 Q2] 
CROSS JOIN
   dbo.[2013 Q3] 
CROSS JOIN
   dbo.[2013 Q4] 
CROSS JOIN
   dbo.[2014 Q1] 
CROSS JOIN
   dbo.[2014 Q2]
```

All of my tables have the identical column names/properties. The error message I receive is

> Column names in each view or function must be unique. Column name XY is specified more than once.

The goal is to query all tables by just querying against the AllQtrs view. Any help?

Comment: You must enlist all columns form your tables in select list giving them unique aliases.

Comment: Instead of a view that you'll have to change every three months, why don't you put all that stuff into a single table that has fields for year number and quarter number.

Comment: Because the tables are incredibly large.

Comment: If they are incredibly large, let's say 1,000,000 entries in one, then cross joining only two will mean you will have 1,000,000 * 1,000,000 = 1 trillion of results. That won't make it faster.

Answer (score 2):

You must specify the names manually and define unique names for them. This way you'll show the columns. An example would be

```
SELECT dbo.[2010 Q3].Column1 AS 2010Q3Column1, 
       dbo.[2010 Q3].Column2 As 2010Q3Column2, 
       dbo.[2010 Q3].Column1 As 2010Q4Column1 
       etc.
```

Btw, make sure that `CROSS JOIN` is really what you want - looks like you actually want to use `UNION ALL` here. `CROSS JOIN` will return cartesian product of all rows from all tables, i.e. if there are 10 rows in each table, it will be 10^16 records, which definitely won't complete in a few decades.

With UNION ALL it will look like:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2 {add here the remaining column names} FROM dbo.[2010 Q3] UNION ALL
SELECT Column1, Column2 {add here the remaining column names} FROM dbo.[2010 Q4] UNION ALL
SELECT Column1, Column2 {add here the remaining column names} FROM dbo.[2011 Q1] UNION ALL
...etc
```

Comment: Thanks.  I changed to Union All, but did not define each column as a unique name.  I'm getting syntax errors:  SELECT            dbo.[2010 Q3].*, dbo.[2010 Q4].*, dbo.[2011 Q1].*, dbo.[2011 Q2].*, dbo.[2011 Q3].*, dbo.[2011 Q4].*, dbo.[2012 Q1].*, dbo.[2012 Q2].*, dbo.[2012 Q3].*, 
                         dbo.[2013 Q2].*, dbo.[2013 Q1].*, dbo.[2012 Q4].*, dbo.[2014 Q1].*, dbo.[2013 Q4].*, dbo.[2013 Q3].*, dbo.[2014 Q2].*
FROM              dbo.[2010 Q3] UNION ALL  dbo.[2010 Q4] UNION ALL

Comment: @ZJAY Edit the question and add there what you tried with the union all

Comment: @ZJAY I added an example how to do this with UNION ALL.

Comment: Thanks Tomas.  So it seems like there is no easy/seamless way to query a single view [All Qtrs] which is another way of querying all of the tables at once?  There are 25 column names in each table (all identical across all quarters), so it is a bit cumbersome to name all of these - no easy work around?

Comment: I would recommend you building proper indexes across the fields you actually need. It will be pretty easy to specify the UNION ALL via copypaste, but I don't believe it will be any faster. On the other hand, indexes can help you a lot. The following link can be helpful: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you on (SQL Server 2008?).  Here's another few tricks, for dealing with long lists of column names, in SQL Server 2005 and later:  (1) in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio), if you right-click on a table name, you'll see an option to `Script Table as`; hover over that, and choose `SELECT To`; hovering over that, select `New Query Editor window`... and you get a script with all the column names listed out.  Or, (2) Open a new query window, right-click anywhere, and select `Design Query in Editor`.  This will give you a graphic interface for creating queries.

Comment: @ZJAY I just realized you might not have seen my comment, above, re' other shortcuts... because I forgot to begin the comment with `@ZJAY`.